# Inner SecurityException while using XmlSerializer

Tags: asp.net, web-services, sharepoint, serialization

While creating a custom Sharepoint web service I received an error while attempting to serialise a class for transmission.

There are no errors with my serializable classes. They are structured in a manner I have used before and can be serialised successfully on a local test environment, the issue only arises when the Sharepoint web service has been deployed.

```
System.InvalidOperationException was caught
  Message=There was an error generating the XML document.
  Source=System.Xml
  StackTrace:
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
       at SPServiceExtensions.DTOSerializerHelper.SerializeDTO(SharepointDTO dto)
  InnerException: System.Security.SecurityException
       Message=Request failed.
       Source=xo46jp-i
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterSharepointDTO.Write4_SharepointDTO(String n, String ns, SharepointDTO o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
            at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterSharepointDTO.Write5_SharepointDTO(Object o)
       InnerException:
```

The inner SecurityException was unfamiliar. What is causing this Exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET uses [different trust levels](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/a55fb31b-5b42-476d-9cae-050ab3fae307.mspx?mfr=true) for it's security policies. This is so applications cannot access the data from other unrelated applications.

Microsoft Sharepoint has [two additional code access levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583158%28v=office.11%29.aspx) of its own and by default runs on **WSS_Minimal.**

As the webservice is operating as a local application on the Sharepoint server it requires **Full Trust**

However Microsoft discourages applying full trust willy nilly. I gather that it potentially allows other applications to call your code which has the potential of being used maliciously to exploit the system.

So a better way to prevent the SecurityException is to modify the projects `AssemblyInfo.cs` and add this attribute `[assembly:AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]` to it.

[Microsoft's article on Code Access Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).